# C# Patterns;for loops

Tags: c#

Develop a C# console application that displays the following pattern. Use for loops (hint:  nested) to generate the patterns. All asterisks should be displayed by a single statement of the form `Console.Write("*");` which displays the asterisks leading up to the number value shown in the example. Note the sequence of each number in turn. You will need to deduce how the numbers are computed (they are the result of a computation) and where that computation will be placed in the loop structures.  You may not hardcode the displayed numbers into your loops.

I already have the "*" but can't figure out the numbers.

The two patterns should look similar to the following:

```
*2
**4
***6
****8
*****10
******12
*******14
********16
*********18
**********20

{
        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)            
            {
                Console.Write("  ");

                for (int col = 0; col <= row; col++)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
            }
        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
        {
            Console.Write("  ");

            for (int col = 10; col > row; col--)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Show us your progress? Your code

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: @dotnetom Looks exactly like one.... but I don't mind people asking help with homework, as long as they've shown extensive effort.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811

Answer (score 3):

> I already have the `"*"` but can't figure out the numbers.

You have the hardest part then: getting the numbers to print is much easier. Note that the number that you print is equal to two times the number of asterisks in front of it. Therefore, what you need to write is `2*n`, where `n` is the limit in the loop that wrote the asterisks (i.e. the `row` plus one in your code).

You can combine the printing with writing the end-of-line mark: replace

```
Console.WriteLine(" ");
```

with

```
Console.WriteLine(2*(row+1));
```

to get the desired result.

Comment: That is not completly correct. He does need to `Console.Write("{0}", (row+1)*2)` because the loop starts at index 0. Otherwise the output would be *0; **2; ***4; ****6;

Comment: @Serv You're right, I missed that. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2):

I decided to make my comment to dasblinkenlight's answer into an answer on its own:

```
for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col <= row; col++) {
        Console.Write("*");
    }

    Console.Write("{0}{1}", (row+1)*2, Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Notice, that the rownumer displayed at the end of the line is calculated as `(row+1)*2`, because your loop starts at index 0. The output would be faulty otherwise. This is followed by a new line.